# GuzzleHTTP Response 400 Status

Tags: php, zoho, guzzle

I have been using GuzzleHttp and here is my code snippet and this appears to manage Session in GuzzleHTTP somehow.

```
    $this->httpMethod=='GET';
    if(!empty($this->httpMethod) && $this->httpMethod=='POST'){
        $response = $this->client->post($finalUrl);
    }else{
        $response = $this->client->request($this->httpMethod, $finalUrl);
    }
```

Unfortunately, I am getting this Fatal Error-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `GET https://creator.zoho.com/api/json/test/view/All_SMS?zc_ownername=zc_owner&raw=1&authtoken=auth_token&scope=crmapi` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"code":2945,"message":"DATATYPE_NOT_MATCHED"}
```

Comment: You're not getting a 400 because of guzzle - guzzle is simply telling you that the server returned a 400 error because of the error `DATATYPE_NOT_MATCHED` (the server returned this). What that error means is up to the API so you should look in the documentation for whatever API you're using to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: The URL put in Browser sends data. So this appears I need to check again and I guess somehow HTTP Client Request is not forming right.

Comment: this appears to manage Session in GuzzleHTTP somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the [Zoho API error codes](https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/creator-error-codes.html).

Code 2945 is an invalid ticket.

Without studying the API documentation in depth, I suspect it is [an authentication problem](https://www.zoho.com/creator/help/api/prerequisites/generate-auth-token.html).

Comment: I am checking. Thanks.